# Displaying ajax data in template page - Framework7

Tags: javascript, ajax, phonegap, html-framework-7

Am playing with Framework7 to do hybrid mobile app development. I have three tabs (bottom fixed), which are `Home`, `Contacts` and `Settings/Profile`

My `app.js` file looks somewhat like this:

```
var $$ = Dom7;

var app  = new Framework7({

    //.....

    data: function () {
        return {
            user_profile : ''               
        }
    },

    on: {
        tabShow( tab )  //-- when a bottom tab is clicked
        {               
            if( $$(tab).attr('id') == 'view-settings' )
            {
                //.. do ajax call and get the response data in "resp"

                app.data.user_profile = resp.response.profile;  //setting the info to app's data

            }           
        }
    },

    routes: routes
});

var settingsView = app.views.create('#view-settings', {
    url: '/settings/'
});
```

And in `routes.js`:

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/contacts/',
    componentUrl: './pages/contacts.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/settings/',
    componentUrl: './pages/settings.html',
  }
];
```

This **Contacts** page contains static content. For the **Home** page, am doing the AJAX API call during the `deviceready` state. Because am setting up some headers for authentication and stuff(for all the AJAX api calls) in there.

The problem am facing is, am unable to display the content in **Settings** page. It is always empty!

Am using this in that template page:

```
<div class="item-title item-label">Full Name - {{$root.user_profile.full_name}}</div>
```

I want to compile that template only when clicking the respective tab button.
Maybe that's the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to read [template7 docs] (http://idangero.us/template7/), specially the `Global context`block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the documentations again and again, I got another way to do this.

So, during the `tabShow` event, I check whether the user is accessing the **Settings/Profile** tab. If so, I check whether an object in `app.data` (eg: `app.data.user_profile` is empty or not(am storing the profile details there). If empty, I would do an AJAX API call to get the profile details. When the profile details is obtained, I would use `app.form.fillFromData()` method to fill the form. Documentation here: https://framework7.io/docs/form.html#form-data-app-methods

Make sure to name the form as well as the input elements in that form, and the same name should be use in the object(key name) when calling the `fillFromData()` function.

And one more thing, for the routes, `/settings/` path, I used `url` instead of the `componentUrl` property to pass the url of the page.

This may not be the best solution, but am still learning. And it seems to have solved by current problem.

Thank you